# Comparing multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have 2 columns:

- Column1: 'Silverado'
- Column2: '1500 Vortec Max Crew Cab'

And I want to match up the record to a string that is 'Silverado 1500'

How would I go about this?

I'm running SQL Server 2014

Thank you

Comment: so do you want to check `Silverado 1500` exists in col2?..Your requirement is not clear,please show expected output for some samples

Comment: No, I want to check if Silverado Silverado 1500 exists across the 2 columns

Comment: total string or any part of string

Comment: Any part of the string

Comment: Sounds like you need to concatenate the strings and then do a `Like'%...'` statement or something along those lines... You'd need to clarify your question first before you could get much more help than that....

Comment: Well, I need it to match up to 'Silverado 1500', but not 'Silverado 2500'

Comment: @JohnBustos, I tried v.vchrModel + ' ' + v.vchrBodyType LIKE '%@vchrModel%', but that didn't give me any results. I'm not sure if the syntax is right though

Comment: See my comment to @BWS's solution....

Comment: I think maybe you want to reorganize into three columns for "Silverado", "1500", "Vortec Max Crew Cab", assuming this fits into your application model.

Comment: @JackPilowsky:you may want to post few more samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE Col1 + ' ' + Col2 LIKE '%Silverado 1500%'
```

Comment: That won't work because there is no space between them,  You need to do `LIKE '%Silverado1500%'`

Comment: To be more exact, I think he wants something like `WHERE Col1 + ' ' + Col2 LIKE '%' + Col3 + '%'`

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but this is the kind of behavior I would expect for a search like this. It will give you matching results for multiple terms and how many terms were matched.

```
DECLARE @SearchTerms TABLE(
    Term VARCHAR(200)
)

DECLARE @Table TABLE (
    Col1 VARCHAR(200),
    Col2 VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Silverado','1500 Vortec Max Crew Cab'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 'Honda','Accord'

DECLARE @xml as xml,@str as varchar(100),@delimiter as varchar(10)
SET @str='Silverado 1500 Crew'
SET @delimiter =' '
SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@str,@delimiter ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml)

INSERT INTO @SearchTerms
    SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(10)') as value FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)


SELECT t.Col1,t.Col2,count(*) [Matching Terms]
FROM @Table t
INNER JOIN @SearchTerms st on t.Col1 like '%' + st.Term + '%' OR t.Col2 like '%' + st.Term + '%'
GROUP BY t.Col1,t.Col2
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```